# Android Studio did not update to 2.1

Tags: android

I would like to update my Android Studio Version to 2.1

[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2wjL.png)

Patch file downloaded but afterwards this info window appears :(

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITaUS.png)

Afterwards Android Studio stays at 1.5.1

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Windows** you have to download the full **IDE** again

> The release is available in the stable, beta, and dev channels, so you
>   can check for updates via Help > Check for Update... (on OSX, look in
>   the Android Studio menu). This will download and install a patch
>   rather than download a full IDE image.

See [Latest Android Studio Canary Build: 2.1 Stable](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest) for more info